# Work profile - Turn off auto rotate / access settings

Tags: applications, settings, system-apps, work-profiles

I am using a work profile (set up via Insular) in order to clone some apps. I have an issue I can't seem to find any info about on the internet and I'm hoping someone can help me here. I am using ColorOS on Android 13 if that has any importance.

I have auto-rotate off on my phone. That means I can use an app while laying on the side and keep portrait mode. If I switch to an app from work profile however, auto-rotate is on and the app will flip. The quick tiles still show it's off so I can't change it from there.

**Issue:** How can I access the settings app for work profile? I cannot clone the settings app. Apparently it's already cloned? But then how do I access it so I can turn auto-rotate off from there? I can see it in the app list but not open it. There is no shortcut anywhere too.

I would be fine with just a way to disable auto-rotate for work profile though.